# Blackberry XPages Theme

Tags: mobile, blackberry, themes, xpages

I have an application using XPages Mobile Controls for iOS.
My customer has Blackberry devices (9900/9800/9320) in his environment and I don't know if IBM provides a custom BBerry theme. These devices have a very small screen and the app navigation is too bad.
The Android/BBerry default theme seems the same of iOS using black/gray colors.

Have anyone ran into this situation in a project?

Comment: does any other mobile theme work for you? XP mobile controls are based on DOJO mobile

Comment: I'm looking for this theme...  Do you have any idea?

Comment: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/mobile/flickrview/part1/